# How to connect properly to Elasticsearch cloud using API key and python lib?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Created API key under [Elastic cloud](https://www.elastic.co/cloud/) (hosted on aws).

Doc [declare](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-api-authentication.html) a proper auth header should be attached:

```
Authorization: ApiKey $EC_API_KEY
```

Using `curl` it works:

```
curl -i -H "authorization: ApiKey LONG_KEY_STRING=="  https://12345.us-east-2.aws.elastic-cloud.com:9243/_health

HTTP/2 200 
x-cloud-request-id: 1234abc
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
content-length: 34
date: Thu, 22 Oct 2020 12:36:54 GMT

{
  "ok": true,
  "status": 200
}
```

But the following python code (`elasticsearch-7.9.1`) fail:

```py
es = Elasticsearch(['https://12345.us-east-2.aws.elastic-cloud.com:9243'], api_key="LONG_KEY_STRING==")
print(es.cluster.health())
```

With error:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "AuthenticationException(401, 'security_exception', 'missing authentication credentials for REST request [/_cluster/health]')",
    "stackTrace": [
        "  File \"/path/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/lambda_local/main.py\", line 153, in execute\n    result = func(event, context._activate())\n",
        "  File \"main.py\", line 35, in handler\n    post_ping_doc(ping, msg[KEY_ID])\n",
        "  File \"main.py\", line 45, in post_ping_doc\n    print(es.cluster.health())\n",
        "  File \"/path/elasticsearch/client/utils.py\", line 152, in _wrapped\n    return func(*args, params=params, headers=headers, **kwargs)\n",
        "  File \"/path/elasticsearch/client/cluster.py\", line 69, in health\n    headers=headers,\n",
        "  File \"/path/elasticsearch/transport.py\", line 392, in perform_request\n    raise e\n",
        "  File \"/path/elasticsearch/transport.py\", line 365, in perform_request\n    timeout=timeout,\n",
        "  File \"/path/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py\", line 269, in perform_request\n    self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)\n",
        "  File \"/path/elasticsearch/connection/base.py\", line 301, in _raise_error\n    status_code, error_message, additional_info\n"
    ],
    "errorType": "AuthenticationException"
}
```

Tried other variations while browsing the net, all with the same result.

Fired up a local `ncat -l 1234` and redirected the request to it. request seems legit...

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:1234
Accept-Encoding: identity
connection: keep-alive
content-type: application/json
user-agent: elasticsearch-py/7.9.1 (Python 3.7.5)
authorization: ApiKey LONG_KEY_STRING==
```

Python code does work with local unsecured ES on docker (not requiring any key).

Currently out of idea, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/master/connecting.html#auth-apikey) you do not need to specify the host. I have tried this and it works for me.

```
es = Elasticsearch(api_key="LONG_KEY_STRING==")
print(es.cluster.health()) # should print a healthy status!
```